# How to read messages in a thread with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

After looking through the docs of discord.py for a painful amount of time, I still can't find a way to get messages from a thread. Hopefully there is a function for this, but am open to other hacky things to get this working.

```py
async for message in channel.history(after=start, before=end):
    if message.type == discord.MessageType.public_thread:
        #await for m in message.fetch_messages()????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
forum = bot.get_channel(111111111111)  # forum channel ID
thread = discord.utils.get(
    forum.threads, id=22222222222)  # thread channel ID
)

# instead of the above could simply do:
# thread = bot.get_channel(22222222)  # thread channel ID

async for message in thread.history(after=start, before=end):
    ...  # do something with message
```